# How to get value of input when it is repeated multiple times

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have 5 modals each one with a unique id.

`<div class="modal fade" id="<?php echo "game-modal-" . $fetch['id'] ?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="Game Modal" aria-hidden="true">`

In the modals I have a hidden input that echo's the id.

`<input type="hidden" name="" value="<?php echo $fetch['id']; ?>" class="game-id">`

When I unhide the inputs it displays the correct id depending on which modal is being displayed. I then have a cancel button in the modal that when clicked should display the id. But it doesnt display the correct id just the first one. Why would it send js the wrong id when it is in a unique modal and whats the best approach to this problem?

`$('.cancel-button').click(function(){
    var gameId = $(".game-id").val();
    alert(gameId);
});`

`<button class="btn btn-outline-light btn-sm cancel-button" type="submit">Cancel</button>`

Comment: `var gameId = $(".game-id").val();` That's not constrained to anything specific; it's just finding the first instance of `class="game-id"`, instead of the one you actually want.

Comment: That's just it! I'm having trouble on getting the specific input.

Comment: Maybe this will be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20357017/jquery-find-input-field-closest-to-button

Comment: Why not give your cancel button a data attribute like `data-gameId="<?php echo $fetch['id']; ?>"` and then change the line `var gameId = $(".game-id").val();` to `var gameId = $(this).attr('data-gameId');`. If you have no other form elements to take care of, this would be my approach.

Comment: @Yolo Thank you so much! That worked!