# Correct way with jquery to get values from multiple input and buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to get value from input. But the forms are generated dynamically and they have the same class. How can i get for example the input value of only one? In the fiddle below if i click on modify always the first button get triggered.

```
<form class="myForm">
    <label for='newName'>file</label>
    <input type='text' class='newName' placeholder='new name'/>
    <input type='button' name='change' class='btnSelected' value='Modify'/>
</form>
<form class="myForm">
    <label for='newName'>file</label>
    <input type='text' class='newName' placeholder='new name'/>
    <input type='button' name='change' class='btnSelected' value='Modify'/>
</form>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".myForm").on('click', '.btnSelected', function() {

        newName = $(".newName").val();
      console.log(newName);
});


});    
</script>
```

Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/jkwv0oha/2/

Comment: change `$(".newName").val()` to `$(this).prev().val()`

Comment: You need to find the ".newName" element that is a sibling of the button that was clicked. Many ways to do it

Comment: Thank you both of you it worked. I think we can close the question. thx

Comment: The [`for` attribute of the `label` element should point to the `id` attribute of the element it labels](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label#attr-for), not the `name`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery: find input field closest to button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20357017/jquery-find-input-field-closest-to-button)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without jQuery, register the `<body>` to listen for `'click'` event then simply delegate the click event so that the event handler `getValue()` is fired only if the user clicked anything with class `.btnSelected`. In order to get the correct `<input>` value, `.previousElementSibling` and `.value` properties were applied to clicked button (referenced to as `event.target`).

```js
const getValue = e => {
  if (e.target.classList.contains('btnSelected')) {
    console.log(e.target.previousElementSibling.value);
  }
};

document.body.onclick = getValue;
```

```html
<form class="xForm">
  <label for='newName'>file</label>
  <input type='text' class='newName' placeholder='new name' />
  <input type='button' name='change' class='btnSelected' value='Modify' />
</form>
<form class="xForm">
  <label for='newName'>file</label>
  <input type='text' class='newName' placeholder='new name' />
  <input type='button' name='change' class='btnSelected' value='Modify' />
</form>
```